# how to solve a first-order order differential equation system with boundary conditions in Matlab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve a ODE system with the following equations:
$$
\frac{\partial{\beta}}{\partial{t}}=k\beta-\frac{\sigma^2\beta^2}{2}+\frac{\delta\beta+u}{\delta\beta+\eta+u}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial{t}}=-k\theta\beta
$$
where the boundary condition:$$\alpha(t)=0,\beta(t)=0$$ and $$k,\sigma,\delta,u,\eta,\theta$$ are given parameters.

In my opinion,this is not a intial value problem, so I cannot use the solver **ode45** directly. **bvp4c** also doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify why bvp4c does not work? It looks like it should. Take a look at the first example on this page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html.

Comment: @Paichu，the boundary condition of bvp4c must be a vector of y, like res = bcfun(ya,yb). But my boundary condition contains two variables, and I can not convert them into one variable condition.

Comment: Let say your function is defined on $[a,b]$. Then your boundary for $\beta$ is $\beta(a) = \beta(b) = 0$. That can be used as the boundary vector values. Also, you can just solve for $\beta$ first, then use that to solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: @Paichu，Thinks. Actually if the function defined on [a,b], my boundary of $\beta$ is only $\beta(b)=0$. I mean I just have one condition and cannot use the solver.

Comment: In that case, you may want to edit your question, which currently has "the boundary condition: $\beta(t) = 0$."